# Riak data types: Are the "_<type-name>" suffixes necessary?

Tags: riak

I am using the Riak `map` data type to store user information in a `users` bucket. When testing this with a simple `curl` call, I noticed that it was necessary to append `_register` to every property name in order for the `curl` request to be accepted.

For example, this fails:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:10018/types/user/buckets/users/datatypes/jsmith \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"update":{"first-name":"John","last-name":"Smith"}}'

Invalid map field name 'first-name'
```

But this works:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:10018/types/user/buckets/users/datatypes/jsmith \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"update":{"first-name_register":"John","last-name_register":"Smith"}}'
```

Do I really need to append `_<type-name>` to every single property?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The examples for data-type Maps show that the suffix to maps must include the `type` [Basho - Riak Data-types Maps](https://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.1/dev/using/data-types/#Maps)